# OBS screen record stopping after awhile

Tags: 20.04, obs-studio

I'm having headaches with OBS, I recorded things that when I started the recordings it looked fine on OBS, then upon reviewing the footage I found I'd been duped by OBS.

I got this for many applications and while recording the whole screen or just a window.

One was discord (I was recording mainly for audio but I would have liked to have the visuals of the avatars lighting up for it to be clearer in the video who is talking) another is a fullscreen game.

The symptom I get watching the outputted mkv is that I switch from OBS to my target app and right as I do I only get that last frame in repeat.

during this time the cursor capture continues to work. we see the right updated cursors and position but it's over a still picture.

sound continues to work too.

Another big thing of note is that I was using the exact same setup for ubuntu 18.04, 18.01.04, 19.04, 19.10 and none of these persented this issue.

however under ubuntu 20.04 I get this new bug. I first tried the ppa version which is what I'm used to using from the previous ubuntu versions and then i tried the snap. same exact behavior.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong? ffmpeg is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! thanks to the bug report [Window Capture Black Screen](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/solved-window-capture-black-screen.47082/).

If I record as a window instead of the whole screen and select the running FA instance initially I would see a black screen in the preview. so initially I thought window recording wasn't possible.

But if you go to the next step you get this screen:

[image: screenshot of Properties for 'Window Capture (Xcomposite)']

And you can enable the option called "alpha-less texture format (Mesa workaround)" (which makes sense because FA is a mesa app) then it works.

(I actually had to toggle on (then off because I don't actually want to swap colors) "Swap red and blue" to force it to apply.

There!